# UI freezes when updating the contents

Tags: android, performance, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager

My app has a ViewPager that holds up to 5 fragments each containing a RecyclerView. When my IntentService fetches new data from the Internet I need to update the data in my UI. This however freezes my UI so the PullDownToRefresh-Animation freezes and I can't scroll or do whatever. Once it has loaded all the data I can move around again so it's no permanent freeze.

I honestly have no idea what I'd have to change in order to maybe handle my data changes or more efficiently or generally what to do against those freezes.

```
public void displayData() {
    int school = mSharedPreferences.getInt(PREFERENCE_SCHOOL, -1);
    String classYearLetter = mSharedPreferences.getString(PREFERENCE_CLASS_YEAR_LETTER, "");
    int classYear = Integer.parseInt(classYearLetter.substring(0, 2));
    String classLetter = classYearLetter.substring(3);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    List<String> tabTitles = new ArrayList<>();

    List<SubstitutionDay> databaseResults;
    if (mSharedPreferences.getBoolean(PREFERENCE_SHOW_WHOLE_PLAN, false)) {
        databaseResults = mDatabaseHandler.getSubstitutionDayList(school, 0, "");
    } else {
        databaseResults = mDatabaseHandler.getSubstitutionDayList(school, classYear, classLetter);
    }


    mMainTabLayout.removeAllTabs();
    for (int n = 0; n < databaseResults.size(); n++) {
        if (databaseResults.get(n).getSubstitutionList().size() > 0) {
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(databaseResults.get(n).getDate());
            String tempDate = dateFormatter.format(calendar.getTime());
            String tempWeekday = weekdayFormatter.format(calendar.getTime());
            tabTitles.add(tempWeekday + " " + tempDate.substring(0, 6));
        }
    }

    if (tabTitles.size() == 0) {
        mMainTabLayout.addTab(mMainTabLayout.newTab().setText("Keine Vertretungen gefunden"));
        mMainViewPager.removeAllViews();
    } else {
        PagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabTitles, "substitution", databaseResults);
        mMainViewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
        mMainTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mMainViewPager);
    }

    mMainViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(mMainTabLayout) {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            toggleRefreshing(state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE);
        }
    });

    mMainTabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            mMainViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });

    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
}
```

The above method gets called from my BroadcastReceiver if there's a new update as well as when I first open my app. An IntentService handles the background work so as far as I know it should not be blocking the UI.

Any idea what I'd need to change in order to fix my issue? If there's any more code I should provide just let me know! Thanks.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue?